# Distinctive features of English diphthongs

Tags: american-english, resources, vowels, diphthongs

I am looking for a table of distinctive features for English dipthongs along the lines of that available for other vowels [here](http://www.benjamins.com/jbp/series/Z/156/workbook/exercise_2.7.html).  I don't trust my purely book learned linguistic skills to produce an accurate feature matrix.

A [tool I wrote](http://shape-of-code.coding-guidelines.com/2012/03/16/generating-sounds-like-and-accented-words/) uses a distinctive feature table based on a very old theory and I would like to update it.

Comment: Do you mean phonemic diphthongs like /ay, aw, oy/, or phonetic diphthongs like [ej] for /e/ or [əʊ] for /o/?

Comment: Something like this?  http://clas.mq.edu.au/phonetics/phonology/features/index.html

Comment: I think phonemic diphthongs is what I am after.

Thanks for the Australian link, which I had seen and ignored because I was after US pronunciation (sorry, did not specify that in the original question).

Comment: What's the question again?

Comment: On the other hand, there's really no such thing as "an accurate feature matrix". Different phonologists have come up with their particular analysis. I wonder if you might be better coming up with your own feature matrix that serves your particular purpose (if it serves your purpose well, then it's "accurate" for your purposes, no?).

Comment: Neil,  I have noticed a surprising amount of variety in the feature matrices I have seen.  The information is used to compute a distance between phonemes which in turn is used by an algorithm that generates words (actually letter sequences) that hopefully sound like the input word.  For the time being I have created a feature matrix that appears to my eyes to be consistent with other vowel features I copied from the link given in my question.

Comment: Is [The Description and Distribution of English Monophthongs
and Diphthongs](http://ebooks.unibuc.ro/filologie/mateescu/pdf/43.pdf) anything like what you are looking for?

Comment: Are you by chance working with a [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) algorithm?

Comment: Here's [One more link](http://www.paulmeier.com/ipa/diphthongs.html) to throw into the mix.

Comment: Great question, but I think that this one is a better fit for http://linguistics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @RegDwight can you migrate this over to [linguistics.se]?

Comment: Migrate as in re-ask the question or as in move the question (I have no idea how)?  I only found out about the Linguistics exchange when I saw the reply from JSB.

Comment: Does the <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipthong#English">wikipedia entry on Dipthongs</a> not give you what you want?

Comment: @Christian - wouldn't this question be more appropriate for the Linguistics site? http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about diphthongs myself, but the only features I can find are described [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=QMsWFsI0YkIC&lpg=PT493&dq=diphthong%20rising%20falling%20opening%20closing%20centring%20english&pg=PT493#v=onepage&q=diphthong%20rising%20falling%20opening%20closing%20centring%20english&f=false). They are:

- closing vs opening (vs centring) (direction of tongue movement)
- wide vs narrow (amount of movement)
- falling vs rising (placement of stress)

Several examples are given, but there is no exhaustive list. Another [source](http://www.punksinscience.org/kleanthes/courses/UCY04F/PLA/phonology.intro.pdf) (see section 5.5) categorizes most/all of the English diphthongs along the closing vs centring dimension (English diphthongs don't open) and the falling vs rising dimension. Still more categorization can be found [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=PzMycyB5sCEC&lpg=PA77&dq=diphthong%20rising%20falling%20opening%20closing%20centring%20english&pg=PA77#v=onepage&q=diphthong%20rising%20falling%20opening%20closing%20centring%20english&f=false). With these sources, you should be able to build a complete table.

Comment: Well, since some of the features on offer overlap, and not all are significant in English, one can build a useful table, but a complete table would be unusable in practice.